# DISTINCT for two out of three columns in with statement

Tags: sql, plsql

Trying to get my query to group but it isn't liking my group by so I have to come up with something else. How do I get one row for every unique Person_iD and ah_person_id combo, doesn't matter which row.

```
WITH w_accnt AS
             (SELECT DISTINCT account.id AS id,
                              account.group_code AS account_number,
                              account.attribute_1 AS group_number,
                              account.source_id AS ah_person_id,
                              weekly.person_id AS person_id                              
                FROM MyAccountTable account
               INNER JOIN MyWeeklyTable weekly
                  ON weekly.account_id = account.id
            
                 ),
```

Example Table

```
Person   AH_PERSON   ACCOUNT_num
A         1           22
B         2           23
B         2           24 
C         3           25
C         4           26
```

What I want back Expected Results

```
Person   AH_PERSON   ACCOUNT_num
A         1           22
B         2           23
C         3           25
C         4           26
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
SELECT MIN(a.id) AS id, MIN(a.group_code) AS account_number,
       MIN(a.attribute_1) AS group_number,
       a.source_id AS ah_person_id,
       w.person_id AS person_id                              
FROM MyAccountTable account a JOIN
     MyWeeklyTable w
     ON w.account_id = a.id
GROUP BY a.source_id, w.person_id
```

Or perhaps window functions:

```
SELECT aw.*
FROM (SELECT a.id, a.group_code AS account_number, a.attribute_1 AS group_number,
             a.source_id AS ah_person_id, w.person_id AS person_id,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.source_id, w.person_id ORDER BY a.id DESC) as seqnum                              
      FROM MyAccountTable account a JOIN
           MyWeeklyTable w
           ON w.account_id = a.id
      GROUP BY a.source_id
     ) aw
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

This gives you more control over which values are returned and ensures that they are all from the same row.